# Can I only show windows that are open on the currently focused workspace on the launcher bar?

Tags: compiz, xubuntu, xfce, workspaces

I have few windows opened on my first workspace, and few on second, but all appear on switch bar in the bottom. I want to have in the bar windows from only one workspace I am using now.

I was looking for an answer in settings of applet, but there is nothing. Also workspaces in XFCE are set on 0, but they come from Compiz. Xubuntu 13.10